# unable to install latest phpUnit in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, phpunit, pear

I'm trying to install PHPUnit in Ubuntu 10.04 but I get these error messages

```
sudo pear install -a pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
Duplicate package channel://pear.phpunit.de/File_Iterator-1.3.3 found
Duplicate package channel://pear.phpunit.de/File_Iterator-1.3.2 found
install failed
```

I tried reinstalling PEAR, upgrading it; updated the PEAR and PHPUnit channel; cleared the PEAR's cache but still no luck, I keep getting the same error.

Does anyone have the same problem and know how to solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Having the same problem here. Any solution would be great.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yep, pointed out by Dex, but thought I'd put it up as an answer as well.

not sure why you need sudo though (taken parts from edorian's answer), this is what I did.

```
pear clear-cache
pear install phpunit/File_Iterator
pear install phpunit/Text_Template
pear install --force --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

basically, file iterator and text template were the two I was getting duplicates on, so those are the one's I had to install individually so it wouldn't fail on those when doing the phpunit install.

Comment: Jayson, were you trying to install the latest version of PHPUnit or an older one? I ask because in my machine, PEAR installed PHPUnit 3.6 (which is good to me anyway) and I think it's because I installed File_Iterator-1.3.2, which corresponds to an older version of PHPUnit.

Comment: In my case, at the time I was installing the latest version of PHPUnit, but I actually needed a 3.6.x version... that led to a couple of other problems that had to be fixed heh. That being said, the duplicate package error was showing up on my first install, so I don't think it was caused by previously installed things.

Comment: Installing the broken dependencies totally did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: This one worked great for me as well, after much 'head, meet wall'.  Haha!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem because the server at work is still on PHP 5.2, and installing PHPUnit directly from PEAR was picking the wrong versions of some packages, which are incompatible with PHP 5.2.

In order to fix the installation:

1) I first **uninstalled** all packages from channel phpunit.

2) Next I installed the **right versions of the conflicting packages**:

```
pear install pear.phpunit.de/File_Iterator-1.3.2
pear install pear.phpunit.de/Text_Template-1.1.2
pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHP_Timer-1.0.2
```

3) Next I could **install phpunit**:

```
[root@DanielGarcia ~]# pear install pear.phpunit.de/phpunit
Did not download optional dependencies: pear.phpunit.de/PHP_Invoker, use --alldeps to download automatically
phpunit/PHPUnit can optionally use package "pear.phpunit.de/PHP_Invoker" (version >= 1.1.0)
downloading PHPUnit-3.6.12.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit-3.6.12.tgz (120,240 bytes)
..........................done: 120,240 bytes
downloading PHP_CodeCoverage-1.1.4.tgz ...
Starting to download PHP_CodeCoverage-1.1.4.tgz (132,781 bytes)
...done: 132,781 bytes
downloading PHPUnit_MockObject-1.1.1.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit_MockObject-1.1.1.tgz (19,910 bytes)
...done: 19,910 bytes
downloading PHP_TokenStream-1.1.4.tgz ...
Starting to download PHP_TokenStream-1.1.4.tgz (9,877 bytes)
...done: 9,877 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit_MockObject-1.1.1
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHP_TokenStream-1.1.4
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHP_CodeCoverage-1.1.4
install ok: channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit-3.6.12**
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem with Ubuntu-10.04. The PHPUnit version which is compatible with PHP 5.3.2 is 3.6. This is what is creating the problem. I fixed it by installing exact versions of all the dependencies. Following are the packages which we need:

- PHPUnit
- File_Iterator-1.3.2
- PHP_Timer-1.0.3
- PHP_TokenStream-1.1.4
- PHPUnit_MockObject-1.1.1
- Text_Template-1.1.2
- PHP_CodeCoverage

Detailed instructions are [here](http://blog.ashwinidhekane.com/installing-phpunit-with-php-5-3-2/)

Comment: Great! Yeah, I noticed Ubuntu Lucid comes with that PHP version but I was struggling to force a previous version of PHPUnit. Thanks for the link. Bookmarking it.

Answer (score 1):

There was a packaging issue recently that lead to that error:

To fix it try:

```
sudo pear install --force --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

and you might have already done that but to leave it for others:

```
sudo pear clear-cache
```

(once it's back up; it seems to have issues at the moment).

Reference issue that was discussed on the bugtracker:

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/687

and the bug in pear:

https://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=19650

Comment: thanks. I couldn't install neither the lastest or an older version. What I did, for now, was to install manually any dependency that threw errors and then installed the phpUnit package.